# Extjs TreePanel after clicking on several row and other operations, previous selected row remains highlightiged

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a ExtJs 4.2 TreePanel. I add some nodes, everything is fine this far. However, if for instance I add another node or have open a context menu on a different node then the current one, the record on which I opened the context menu is highlighted (which is correct), but the previous selected node remains highlighted (which is incorect, is this a bug from ExtJs?)
Did anyone else encounter a similar problem?

Comment: Your tree could have selection model mode [`MULTI`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.selection.TreeModel-cfg-mode), or just some means of preventing selection on context menu. Show your code, better in a fiddle.

Comment: selection mode is single